# EF Core One to One relationship on many tables allows duplicate entries

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I am using EF Core and I tried to create a one-to-one relationship between three tables (Car, ElectricCar and PetrolCar)

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string RegistrationNumber { get; set; }

    public ElectricCar Company { get; set; }
    public PetrolCar Trust { get; set; }
}

public class ElectricCar
{
    public int ElectricCarId { get; set; }
    public double BatteryCapacityWattage{ get; set; }

    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
}

public class PetrolCar
{
    public int PetrolCarId { get; set; }
    public double TankCapacity { get; set; }

    public int CarId { get; set; }
    public Car Car { get; set; }
}


public partial class CarDbContext : Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext
{
    public CarDbContext()
    {
    }

    public CarDbContext(DbContextOptions<CarDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<ElectricCar> ElectricCar { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Car> Car { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PetrolCar> PetrolCar { get; set; }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=DESKTOP-PC\\SQLLOCAL;Database=OneToOneEFCoreCar;Trusted_Connection=True;");
        }
    }
}
```

and the code that inserts the data:

```
CarDbContext context = new CarDbContext();

context.Car.Add(new Car
{
    RegistrationNumber = "EL123",
    Company = new ElectricCar() { BatteryCapacityWattage = 2000 }
});

context.Car.Add(new Car
{
    RegistrationNumber = "PETR123",
    Trust = new PetrolCar() {  TankCapacity = 50 }
});
context.SaveChanges();
```

That works without any issue and creates the following data
[image]

When I go to the PetrolCar I insert a new row with CarId = 1 and it accepts it without giving any error although that CarId is used in the ElectricCar table as CarId.
Is there any way to restrict this?

Comment: `When I go to the PetrolCar I insert a new row with CarId = 1 and it accepts it without giving any error although that CarId is used in the ElectricCar table as CarId.` - Are you expecting a Car can only be in either `PatrolCar` or `ElectricCar`? Can not be in two at time same type? isn't it?

Comment: Yes indeed. Can only be in either PetrolCar or ElectricCar

Comment: Problem is in your design. Then way you have design your model it would be possible because one-to-one uniqueness will be guaranteed in the child table individually. You have to redesign you model classes. Shall I propose that?

Comment: @TanvirArjel this is how my models are based on the business. What are your proposed changes?

Comment: Is the current model structure is your, your desired requirement would not possible. My proposed structure would serve the same business logic as you are currently wanting but model structure would be changed

Comment: Click on this chat:  https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188541/room-for-tanvirarjel-and-pantonis

Comment: As I explained in the chat your proposed solution is not helpful for my scenario

Answer (score 0):

If you're entirely set on keeping your object models / data structure the same as it is above then a unique constraint across the two tables isnt really natively achievable.

One possible in code solution (though its not particularly clean, so I would suggest restructuring your data over this, though that seems to be something you would like to avoid) is to override the `SaveChanges` method.

something along the lines of:

```
public override SaveChanges()
{
    var petrolCars = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(e is PetrolCar).ToList();

    foreach(var pCar in petrolCars)
    { 
        if(query the database for electric cars to see if car id exists)
        {
            do some sort of error processing and avoid saving;
        }
    }

    base.SaveChanges();
}
```

it does mean creating a context class that inherits from the default context, though it adds a lot of flexibility in terms of doing something like this (obviously you would want to handle the other cases too of cars having the same id in the other direction)